# combining query for query optimisation

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

I am stuck with some requirement,
this my 1st query
`SELECT price FROM resdential WHERE (CITY LIKE '$Location') AND ( Bedrooms='$Bedrooms' AND Bathsroom='$Bathroom')`

I want to search for apartment when city is London and city is any other(Dorchester in case),
**(prioritising London is essential)**
now every time I get results only from London , and I need combined result, combined London and Dorchester result or any other city results together, need help
yeah you can say use * but, first I want to search for London den any other city

Comment: You can search using a single query and either return * or City, Price then use two arrays to prioritize London results. Have PHP code bellow to show my approach in answer. Hope this is what your are looking for.

Comment: Without escaping, your web site is subject to "SQL injection".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT City, Price FROM resdential WHERE ( Bedrooms=2 AND bathrooms=2) ORDER BY (CITY= 'London') DESC , CITY`
this really worked for me, 
bdw thanks for all your help, I really appreciate , You helped me too go in right direction

Comment: Add this to make it faster:  `INDEX(bedrooms, bathrooms)`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?:

`SELECT price FROM resdential WHERE (CITY IN ('$Location')) AND ( Bedrooms='$Bedrooms' AND Bathsroom='$Bathroom')`

`$Location` would be a list of cities where London is included.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as a right answer.

Comment: Add this to make it faster:  `INDEX(bedrooms, bathrooms, city)`

Answer (score 0):

I would have a list of cities near london on hand in your script(or from a database) search for city="london" or city="city2" or city="city3" then handle the prioritization of London inside your logic. For example

```
$prioList=aray();
$nonPrioList=array();
$results=mysqli_query("SELECT City, Price FROM resdential WHERE CITY IN '$selectedCity' ")
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
  if($row['City']=="London"){
    array_push($prioList,$row);
  }else{
    array_push($nonPrioList,$row);
  }

}
```

That should give you two arrays, one with your london results and the other with your non london results.

Comment: I was going with another solution, But now I'll try your solution
this was my solution 

`SELECT City, Price FROM resdential  WHERE ( Bedrooms=2 AND bathrooms=2) ORDER BY (CITY= 'London') DESC , CITY`

Comment: which automatically gives london reults first, is this good idea?

Comment: I honestly wasn't aware you could use the order by in that way.